How to create oil-painting-like texture?
I am trying to replicate something similar to the following screengrabs.
.

It is an exaggerated 3D texture of an oil painting. Up to this point, I had been trying to sculpt it, primarily using the cloth tool in Blender, but it did not quite achieve the painting-like result.
I was wondering how to create such a look, and is it possible to make it procedural?
Here is the final look of the model.

EDIT:
I have used a displacement modifier with two textures, Stucci and Noise, with the following parameters:



Although it gave me much closer and more realistic look, it still could be significantly improved.


You might try something with dynamic paint and displacement simulating real brush strokes, but I’m not sure this is possible directly in Blender alone. I think your next best shot is to possibly use a photo to painting filter in an external image editing software, then find the brightness difference between the original and the effected, and use that difference as a displacement texture.
